# Create a hash from an array of keys

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have looked at other questions in SO and did not find an answer for my specific problem.

I have an array:

```
a = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

I want to convert this array to a hash where the array elements become the keys in the hash and all they the same value say 1. i.e hash should be:

```
{"a" => 1, "b" => 1, "c" => 1, "d" => 1}
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

My solution, one among the others :-)

```
a = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
h = Hash[a.map {|x| [x, 1]}]
```

Answer (score 30):

There are several options:

- [`to_h`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h) with block:

  ```
  a.to_h { |a_i| [a_i, 1] }
  #=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>1, "c"=>1, "d"=>1}
  ```
- [`product`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-product) + `to_h`:

  ```
  a.product([1]).to_h
  #=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>1, "c"=>1, "d"=>1}
  ```
- [`transpose`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose) + `to_h`:

  ```
  [a,[1] * a.size].transpose.to_h
  #=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>1, "c"=>1, "d"=>1}
  ```

Answer (score 5):

```
a = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

4 more options, achieving the desired output:

```
h = a.map{|e|[e,1]}.to_h
h = a.zip([1]*a.size).to_h
h = a.product([1]).to_h
h = a.zip(Array.new(a.size, 1)).to_h
```

All these options rely on [Array#to_h](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h), available in Ruby v2.1 or higher

Answer (score 4):

```
a = %w{ a b c d e }

Hash[a.zip([1] * a.size)]   #=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>1, "c"=>1, "d"=>1, "e"=>1}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
hash = Hash[a.map { |k| [k, value] }]
```

This assumes that, per your example above, that `a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` and that `value = 1`.

Comment: You don't need the `flatten`, [`Hash[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) can take an Array of Arrays.

Comment: Hash[] doesn't seem to take an array of arrays unfortunately: Hash[ [1, 2], [3, 4] ] => {[1, 2]=>[3, 4]}

Comment: @AsfandYarQazi: Just do this then: `Hash[ *[[1, 2], [3, 4]].flatten ]`

Answer (score 3):

```
["a", "b", "c", "d"].inject({}) do |hash, elem|
  hash[elem] = 1
  hash
end
```

Comment: [`each_with_object`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) would be a better fit here.

Comment: @muistooshort It definitely would be, but it's not something I've used enough for it to come to mind when I'm coding. Thanks! `:)`

Comment: I use it a lot as that extra return value in the block looks lonely :)

Comment: @muistooshort And more importantly I always forget it and then get `undefined method []=` at first `:P`

Answer (score 3):

If your project includes Rails 6 or newer (or you are willing to import [ActiveSupport](https://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport)), then you can use [Enumerable#index_with](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-index_with):

```rb
%i[a b c].index_with { 0 }

# => {a: 0, b: 0, c: 0}
```

You can optionally pass the array element into the block:

```rb
%w[a b c].index_with { |x| x.upcase }

# => {"a" => "A", "b" => "B", "c" => "C"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
h = a.inject({}){|h,k| h[k] = 1; h}
#=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>1, "c"=>1, "d"=>1}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ['1','2','33','20']

Hash[a.flatten.map{|v| [v,0]}.reverse]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{}.tap{|h| %w(a b c d).each{|x| h[x] = 1}}
```